# Is the golden ratio defined in Python?

Tags: python, math

Is there a way to get the golden ratio, *`phi`*, in the standard python module? I know of *`e`* and *`pi`* in the `math` module, but I might have missed *`phi`* defined somewhere.

Comment: Yes a quick google search reveals that scipy has it: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/constants.html

Comment: I thought this was a good question since I was wondering the same thing. @Banana

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[`scipy.constants`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/constants.html) defines the golden ratio as `scipy.constants.golden`. It is nowhere defined in the standard library, presumably because it is easy to define yourself:

```
golden = (1 + 5 ** 0.5) / 2
```

Answer (score 5):

The standard library doesn't. However, since you are importing **math** anyway, *phi* may be calculated the same way *pi* would be calculated:

```
>>> import math
>>> pi = 4 * math.atan(1)
>>> pi
3.141592653589793
>>> pi = math.acos(-1)
>>> pi
3.141592653589793
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
>>> phi = ( 1 + math.sqrt(5) ) / 2
>>> phi
1.618033988749895
```

The reason **math** has *pi* and *e* defined but not *phi* may be because no one asked for it.

---

The python **math** docs says [math.pi](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/math.html#math.pi) is "The mathematical constant π = 3.141592..., to available precision". However, you may calculate four times the arc tangent of one and get [roughly the same result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Modern_quest_for_more_digits): `pi = 4 * math.atan(1)`, or `pi = math.acos(-1)`:

```py
>>> math.pi == math.acos(-1) == 4 * math.atan(1)
True
```

The same could be said about *phi*, which is not readily available as `math.phi` but you may find the nearest available precision with the [regular formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Calculation): `phi = ( 1 + math.sqrt(5) ) / 2`.

---

Libraries that define or provide a "shortcut" to the golden ratio are these:

#### Scipy

Scipy [calculates a static value for the algebraic formula using standard math package at import time](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b4a970bf4eba1065ea31f8d0988cd4ec523a07d4/scipy/constants/_constants.py#L70) and it's the same thing as defining it yourself (specifically to cpython both will be computed at compile time):

```py
import math as _math
golden = golden_ratio = (1 + _math.sqrt(5)) / 2
print(golden)
```

#### MpMath

Mpmath [calculates the algebraic formula at call time to supplied precision](https://github.com/mpmath/mpmath/blob/1258e33e1618a6c537947775a03a7746362c4cee/mpmath/libmp/libelefun.py#L282):

```py
import mpmath
print(mpmath.mp.phi)
```

#### Sympy

The closest thing to a definition of golden ratio is the [sympy's singleton GoldenRatio](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/26f7bdbe3f860e7b4492e102edec2d6b429b5aaf/sympy/core/numbers.py#L4094-L4154) which uses the mpmath float (mpf) calculated at call time:

```py
import sympy
print(float(sympy.S.GoldenRatio))
```

#### Sage

Sage Math goes further allowing you to [calculate phi in many different ways](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/84f02afa5c85e98aeba55c13e09d414871e6e35e/src/sage/symbolic/constants.py#L754).

Comment: The wording of this answer makes it sound like the limited precision of math.pi is a bug. It's not a bug. [Python uses doubles internally.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error) That's why the docs say "to available precision".

`4*math.atan(1)` will not give you a "better approximation", because you're still using doubles underneath. Yes, even "if you have a supercomputer". :) You don't need a supercomputer to generate more than 53 bits of pi.

Comment: I figured the [truncated constant I had originally referenced](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cb9879b948a19c9434316f8ab6aba9c4601a8173/Modules/mathmodule.c#L75) is not the result of calling `math.pi`, but rather [used in the reflection formula for the gamma function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cb9879b948a19c9434316f8ab6aba9c4601a8173/Modules/mathmodule.c#L70). Will update the answer to acknowledge my mistake.